# Troubleshooting server connectivity

Tags: troubleshooting

I went for an interview recently and I was asked if a server was experiencing slow file transfer what would you do troubleshoot the issue?

The could only think of checking speed/duplex. What else can be checked?

Comment: When troubleshooting, always start at layer-1 and work your way up from the physical to the application.  Don't randomly check different things; you need a plan to determine the root cause.  Test things one at a time, and check for problem resolution after each change.

Comment: TCP sliding window, you can see it if you packet capture.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is more a question about performance than connectivity.

There's many thing to check to troubleshoot such issues

You could check :

Regarding the machines involved :

- server health : cpu usage, memory usage, disk subsystem load (I/O counters), network usage
- server logs
- client health
- client logs

You may perform the test from a different client, and event a different operating system to determine if the issue is client side or server side...

Regarding the network between the client and the server:

- topology : are all connection appropriate speeds (for example if you expect a Gbs transfer rate, and there's a 100Mbs switch somewhere...)
- the switches health and configuration
- if there's a router in the middle that could be the bottleneck
- the cabling can easily cause performance issues

You may connect the client on another port / another switch, etc...

Actually the idea is to look at each element of the chain and eliminate them one by one.